# using jscrambler with php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

wanted to know if there any way to use php variable with javascript and jscrambler

i am not able to make it work

i want to hide download file url using jscramble and php
using direct link it does work

but when i replace the link with php variable it does not work 
and i need to use php variable for generating links 
i have tried obfuscation also 
the PHP code are actually strings

```
 <?php echo $file->generateDirectDownloadUrlForMedia(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jscrambler currently does not parse PHP blocks.

You'll have to implement a build script or something to replace the PHP block with HTML or JavaScript. Then submit the result to Jscrambler.
You can for instance run PHP in the shell and cache the result as plain JavaScript files, and then submit those to Jscrambler. It's a two step process, but can be fully automated.

1. php myscript.php > myscript.js
2. submit myscript.js to jscrambler.com

You can use any API client they have. e.g. 
https://github.com/jscrambler/node-jscrambler

Comment: I added more detail to the response.